# addEventListener() no funciona en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy queriendo hacer un *To-Do list*. Mi problema es que cuando quiero apretar sobre el botón de la tarea para seleccionar la tarea debería ejecutarse la función `changeTaskState` al utilizar `addEventListener()`, pero no me la ejecuta nunca a la función cuando hago click sobre el botón, es como si no seleccionara nada, alguna idea?

```js
// Tasks Container
const tasksContainer = document.getElementById('tasksContainer');

let taskNum = 1 ;

const add = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   const { value } = event.target.taskText;
   if (!value) {
       return;
   }
   else {
       const taskHtml = document.createElement('div');
       taskHtml.classList.add('task', 'roundBorder');
       taskHtml.textContent = '('+taskNum+')'+' '+value;
       taskHtml.setAttribute('id', taskNum);
       taskHtml.addEventListener('click', changeTaskState);
       tasksContainer.prepend(taskHtml);
       taskObject = {
                   id: taskNum,
                   task: value
       }
       taskHtml.outerHTML+='<button type="submit" onclick = "editButton(taskObject)" class="editTaskButton">Edit</button>';
       event.target.reset();

       //add the task in the database
       //requestPost(taskObject);

       taskNum++;
   }
};

const changeTaskState = event => {
   event.target.classList.toggle('done');
};

const renderOrderedTasks = () => {
   order().forEach(el => tasksContainer.appendChild(el))
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="list roundBorder">
       <form onsubmit="add(event)" >
           <input type="text" name="taskText" id = "text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="New task" class="roundBorder">
           <button type="submit" class="addTaskButton">+</button>
           <button type="button" onclick="deleteTasks()" href="#" class="orderButton roundBorder" onclick="renderOrderedTasks()">Delete</button>
       </form>
       <div id="tasksContainer">
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nunca he usado `outerHTML` y de hecho no se muy bien que hace (voy a investigarlo ahora), pero he probado tu código remplazando  `outerHTML` por `innerHTML` y funciona justo como requieres.

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que estás llamando a una función que no existe cuando creas cada task, tendrías que llamar directamente a changeTaskState(taskNum), y al capturar el evento en realidad estás capturando el evento del botón, no del contenido de la task.. Capaz lo siguiente te sirve, eliminé el addEventListener en taskHTML, cambié la función que llama el botón al crear cada item en la lista, y esto lo encerré en backticks para pasarle el numero de la tarea, entonces en la función changeTaskState capturo la lista por su id y le hacemos el toggle a la clase.

Archivo JavaScript:

```
// Tasks Container
const tasksContainer = document.getElementById("tasksContainer");

let taskNum = 1;

const add = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { value } = event.target.taskText;
  if (!value) {
    return;
  } else {
    const taskHtml = document.createElement("div");
    taskHtml.classList.add("task", "roundBorder");
    taskHtml.textContent = "(" + taskNum + ")" + " " + value;
    taskHtml.setAttribute("id", taskNum);
    tasksContainer.prepend(taskHtml);
    taskObject = {
      id: taskNum,
      task: value,
    };
    taskHtml.outerHTML += `<button type="submit" onclick = "changeTaskState(${taskNum})" class="editTaskButton">Edit</button>`;
    event.target.reset();

    //add the task in the database
    //requestPost(taskObject);

    taskNum++;
  }
};

const changeTaskState = (taskNumber) => {
  document.getElementById(taskNumber).classList.toggle("done");
};

const renderOrderedTasks = () => {
  order().forEach((el) => tasksContainer.appendChild(el));
};
```

En CSS agregué esto para probar:

```
.done {
text-decoration-line: line-through;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Carga los elementos una vez que se termino de cargar la pagina

*document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
aqui cargas las tareas que se agregaron
})*